# Android Soft Keyoard hiding half EditText if mode is adjustpan

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest, android-softkeyboard

Android SoftKeyoard hiding half `EditText` if `windowSoftInputMode="adjustpan"`.. see the Picture
Keyboard hiding half `EditText` Layout :
[image]

Also I tried `windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` but its taking `tabsLayout` to up... see the Picture..[image]

Please help me..

Comment: Have scrollview?

Comment: Yes, `NestedScrollView` but not inside the `editText` and `TabsLayout`... its are fixed not scrollable.. and i tried `android:isScrollContainer="false"` and `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`... but not working..

Comment: Any solutions bro?

Comment: No... let me know if you got...

Comment: @RamachandranA did you find any solution?